# Why cannot invoke impl.persistence.entity.TimerEntity.calculateRepeat ()?

Tags: java, camunda

I am getting the following error while working with the bmpn scheme on a timer every 15 minutes. What could be the reason for this and how can it be fixed?

[image]

I haven't tried anything because I don't know what the problem is and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, but most likely you have a transaction that got invalidated after/during task execution. Doing so makes Camunda repeat the execution of the failed task. But since the task did not fail itself, Camunda did not not register a failing job, that is to be re-executed to execute the task again. If during task execution, then your task is probably a service task and most likely you manually invalidated the transaction in the code called by the task. If that happens without throwing an exception that propagates to Camunda, then Camunda does not know how to handle the situation properly.

See also https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.19/user-guide/process-engine/error-handling/ for how error handling is usually done in Camunda and https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.19/user-guide/process-engine/transactions-in-processes/ for how transactions work in Camunda.